# error with Breezyslam (Descriptor length mismatch)

Tags: slam, raspberry-pi, python

so I was working on a slam project and using the Breezyslam repo [link](https://github.com/simondlevy/BreezySLAM), I am always getting this error, I don't know where I am getting it wrong, can someone help?

```
File "/home/robopi/Slam/py_slam/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rplidar.py", line 214, in _read_descriptor

raise RPLidarException('Descriptor length mismatch')

rplidar.RPLidarException: Descriptor length mismatch
```

I am running the examples from breezyslam - rpslam.py

I am using raspberry pi 4 and rplidar A1

i have tried another repo which uses breezyslam then i am getting this error

```
File "/home/robopi/Slam/py_slam/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_rplidar.py", line 280, in _read_response
    raise RPLidarException("Wrong body size")
adafruit_rplidar.RPLidarException: Wrong body size
```

that repo is [link](https://github.com/AdroitAnandAI/SLAM-on-Raspberry-Pi)

i am just trying to build a slam using python

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Pedakolimi Harish. When I [search your first repo I don't see `rplidar.py`](https://github.com/simondlevy/BreezySLAM/search?q=rpylidar.py), and when I [search the second repo I don't find `adafruit_rplidar.py`](https://github.com/AdroitAnandAI/SLAM-on-Raspberry-Pi/search?q=adafruit_rplidar.py). I actually don't find either term in either repo. The folder structure says `/robopi/Slam/py_slam/` - are you sure you've linked the correct repos? Or, are you sure you're working in the projects you think you're working in?

Comment: @Chuck  rplidar.py is from the package that is required to run this, this is the link for that https://github.com/Roboticia/RPLidar, and the second one is the same it is a package https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_RPLIDAR  using these when I run https://github.com/simondlevy/BreezySLAM/blob/master/examples/rpslam.py  this I am getting this error.

Comment: Have you verified the port used by the RP Lidar is correct and the lidar is on? That's the only thing really that I'm seeing that seems questionable. Otherwise I'd try copy/pasting [the sample code](https://github.com/Roboticia/RPLidar/blob/master/rplidar.py#L3-L21) exactly as given in the `rplidar.py` file and see if you still get the error.

Comment: @Chuck yes lidar is connected correctly and it is rotating, I can also see a green light, and when I try that sample code it shows the same error

Comment: Are you sure it's on the correct port? Your code and the example both use USB0.

Comment: @Chuck no that is not the problem it is in the correct port

Comment: Not sure what else would be the issue then, you'll have to attach a debugger and see what you're getting. The code defines `DESCRIPTOR_LEN = 7`, tries to read that many bytes, and then errors if it doesn't get that many bytes. You should be [seeing what it's receiving](https://github.com/Roboticia/RPLidar/blob/master/rplidar.py#L212) just before you get the error. You might also find Wireshark useful for logging and investigating the packets going across the wire.

Comment: @Chuck in line 212 I am receiving its value as  b''  I thing everything is going wrong here only